# Read file in UTF-8 encoding and convert to byte array

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, inputstream

I can do this but this question is more to know about what is the best way to achieve this.

I can do following to get the file in buffered reader

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

What is the best way to proceed after this?

Comment: The requirement itself does not quite make sense. Look: UTF-8 is an **encoding**. I.E.: A parameter to convert characters to bytes (and vice-versa). Every conversion must have its proper encoding. So if you read a file (which is always a sequence of **bytes**) with a specific encoding, it's because it should be converted to **chars**. OK. Then, if it must be converted back again to bytes, the same encoding must be used, so... it becomes a pure **do+undo**. You can read the file as bytes and forget about the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is often the simplest one:

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

PS: If you have a `File` object instead of string representation of the path, then just convert the `File` to `Path`:

```
Path path = file.toPath()
```

Comment: First requirement is to read the file in UTF format and then process further

Comment: UTF is not a format, but an encoding scheme. If your file is already UTF-8 encoded, you just have to read it. Nothing more